# Ship button not showing at order section Magento ver. 2.2.6

Tags: magento2

Ship button not showing at order section Magento ver 2.2

Order section

https://i.stack.imgur.com/yOhL7.png

Comment: URL is not working. Please upload image or correct the url.

Comment: please see again

Comment: What is the status of the order with the missing ship button?